# Some fields of my Excel databar are not colored

Tags: c#, excel

I have a problem when creating an Excel dataBar programatically. I have some fields that are not colored (and they are on the range).

[image: The databar]

I adapted a VBA code in C# to do this.
The VBA code :

```
`Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("F6:F14").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).ShowValue = True
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
        .Color = 2668287
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).AxisColor
        .Color = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("H11").Select
End Sub`
```

Adapted in C# :

```
 Excel.Range last = 
         wsMce.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, 
       Type.Missing);
                Excel.Range range = wsMce.get_Range("E6:E" + last.Row);
    var dataBar = range.FormatConditions.AddDatabar();

    dataBar.ShowValue = true;

    //dataBar.MinPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMin;
    //dataBar.SetFirstPriority.MinPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMin;
    //dataBar.SetFirstPriority.MaxPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMax;

    dataBar.BarColor.Color = Color.Orange;
    dataBar.BarColor.TintAndShade = 0;
    dataBar.BarFillType = Excel.XlDataBarFillType.xlDataBarFillSolid;
    dataBar.Direction = Constants.xlContext;
    dataBar.NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = Excel.XlDataBarNegativeColorType.xlDataBarColor;
    dataBar.BarBorder.Type = Excel.XlDataBarBorderType.xlDataBarBorderNone;
    dataBar.AxisPosition = Excel.XlDataBarAxisPosition.xlDataBarAxisAutomatic;
    dataBar.AxisColor.Color = 0;
    dataBar.AxisColor.TintAndShade = 0;
    dataBar.NegativeBarFormat.Color.Color = 255;
    dataBar.NegativeBarFormat.Color.TintAndShade = 0;
```

I did'nt succeed to adapt the MinPoint and MaxPoint properties and maybe that's where the color problem comes from.
I tried this

```
dataBar.SetFirstPriority.MinPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMin;
        dataBar.SetFirstPriority.MaxPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMax;
```

And this

```
dataBar.MinPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMin;
        dataBar.MaxPoint.Modify = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMax;
```

And also this

```
dataBar.MinPoint = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMin;
        dataBar.MaxPoint = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMax;
```

but it always raises an exception.

Thank for your helps !
Regards

EDIT : I also find that in VBA `Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlDataFieldScope` but i didn't know how to adapt it in C#, i tried that but not working :  `dataBar.ScopeType = Excel.XlPivotConditionScope.xlDataFieldScope;`

Comment: Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer, it's tricky...
The Scope type raise an exception because the range has to be in the column of data and the problem of color is also due to the minpoint and maxpoint property
How to use :

```
    dataBar.MinPoint.Modify(Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMin);    
dataBar.MaxPoint.Modify(Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueAutomaticMax);
    dataBar.ScopeType = Excel.XlPivotConditionScope.xlDataFieldScope;
```